# Arduino Attiny 85 IR library compiler error

Tags: library, attiny, avr, ir, atmel-studio

I'm about to ask a question for the most common problem which everyone has with `attiny85` and the IR library. I will try to make this question as simple as possible.

### Few things about the lib and the chip

First of all the lib https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote works great on the `UNO` and it's the best out there.

The `Attiny85` is the smallest chip you can get able to run Arduino code. It has alot of limitations but it worth it!

### The common problem

`Attiny85` uses different timers from the normal Attiny and Atmega chips which makes it impossible to run the standard libraries. There are some fixes for some libs. For example the `IR Remote` has a version which **ALMOST** works with the chip and it can be found over here: http://gammon.com.au/Arduino/IRremote_Attiny.zip

However the problem lies in the core. The first time i used the patched `IR` i had the `MIT High Low Media Group` versino 1 of the core files which bearly worked but it was the first released so...

After reading this guide:http://www.instructables.com/id/Attiny-IR-library/?ALLSTEPS I used an updated core which can be found here: https://arduino-tiny.googlecode.com/files/arduino-tiny-0100-0017.zip

### And the final problem

Even with the updated core i still got *only 1* last error.

```
Compiling 'Shit' for 'ATtiny85 @ 8 MHz  (internal oscillator; BOD disabled)'
IRremoteInt.h:101: error: 'RAWBUF' was not declared in this scope
Error compiling
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

### Links

1. MIT high-low group first version: http://highlowtech.org/?p=1229
2. Tutorial for the chip and the IR: http://www.instructables.com/id/Attiny-IR-library/?ALLSTEPS
3. The IR original lib: https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote
4. Updated core: https://arduino-tiny.googlecode.com/files/arduino-tiny-0100-0017.zip

**Just in case you wanna know i'm using the Atmel Studio 6 with the Visual Micro plugin instead of the crappy-arduino-IDE**

Answer (score 1):

`RAWBUF` is defined in IRremote.h. Make sure you include that header before including IRremoteInt.h.

Comment: it worked but not im getting this:
Upload failed. Did you select the correct upload method for this board?
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at processing.app.debug.AvrdudeUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(String buildPath, String className, Boolean verbose, Boolean ProgrammerUploadUsing, String mcuProgrammerOverrideName)
   at processing.app.SketchEditor.Upload(Boolean verbose)

Comment: That's a problem with your build environment, not the code.

Comment: Indeed. I upload it through the IDE and its working however the receiver is just dead. nothinf happens when i press the button

Comment: Keep your Visual Micro up to date and the error above will not appear :)